# javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, func

I am working on a project and need to implement a function called magic_inc that increments or decrements a given value based on a specific logic. The goal of this function is to apply a custom sequence of increments or decrements to the input value. Here's the sequence:

Comment: I would suggest approaching this using TDD - that way, you can focus on a single requirement per iteration. Once you have something in place, you will be able to refine it, all the while keeping the existing passing tests passing.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? That's so little code that debugging it should not be that hard

Comment: I can't tell why `17, 'dec'` _should_ get you 9 as result, and _not_ the 10 you are getting? Having trouble to actually "see" that in your explanation of how those sequences are supposed to work.

Comment: There are (at least) two distinct questions here. Your rounding of malformed input is an entirely separate problem from the actual incrementing logic. If I understand your increment logic, you want to increment the most significant digit, until it wraps over, at which point you want to shift the entire number up or down by a power of ten, so that only the most significant digit can ever be non-zero?

Comment: The function handles both the "inc" mode (incrementing) and "dec" mode (decrementing) based on the given logical sequence. If the value is less than the smallest increment in the corresponding mode, it returns the smallest increment itself. Otherwise, it increments the most significant digit until it reaches the next value in the sequence or wraps over to the next power of ten.

The function also takes care of rounding malformed input by returning 0 if the input is not a valid number or is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd utilize scientific notation to quickly get the coefficient and the exponent.

Cleanup: truncate the coefficient to an int.

Then just take care of the special cases like `1 -> 0.9` and `-0.9 -> -1` otherwise increment/decrement the coefficient.

```js
function magic_inc(value, mode) {
  if (typeof value !== 'number' || value === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  let [a,b] = value.toExponential().toLowerCase().split("e");
  a = parseInt(a, 10);
  
  if(mode === "inc") a = a===-1 ? -.9 : a+1;
  if(mode === "dec") a = a===1 ? .9 : a-1;
  
  return +`${a}e${b}`;
}

console.log(magic_inc(0.5, 'inc')); // Output: 0.6
console.log(magic_inc(-0.3, 'inc')); // Output: -0.2
console.log(magic_inc(1568.548, 'inc')); // Output: 2000
console.log(magic_inc(17, 'dec')); // Output: 9
```

Comment: ingenious approach